# I want to give multiple conditions in ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<button type="button" class="btn-submit upload smooth-hover" data-prod-idx="{{index}}" data-prod-id="{{prod.ProductId}}"
ng-click="vm.onUpload($event, index, prod.ProductId)" 
ngf-select="vm.uploadAttachments($event, $files, $invalidFiles)" multiple accept="image/*,.pdf,*.doc,*.docx" ngf-capture="'camera'"
ngf-max-size="5MB" 
ng-disabled="prod.Product_Status === 'Approved||Not Approved'">
Upload Documents</button>
```

1. I have different product status condition depending on that I want to disable the button. I am having a problem with or condition in `ng-disable`. Its not disabling the button if i give to conditions.

2.IF clicked on disabled button it should pop-up the alert message (Not using Jquery)
Every condition have different error msg (Conditions in ng-disabled)

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 3):

Your condition code is wrong

```
ng-disabled="prod.Product_Status === 'Approved'|| prod.Product_Status === 'Not Approved'"
```

In case 2, you can remove ng-disable and, on click function, you could made with this way:

```
function onUpload($event, $files, prod.ProductId){
    if(prod.Product_Status === 'Approved'|| prod.Product_Status === 'Not Approved'){
        alert("Message")
        return;
    }
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Carlos Franco.

Comment: Do you have any idea about part 2?

Comment: if this code was mine, i wouldn't use ng-disabled. I would verify the condition in click function. @Mohit

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
ng-disabled="prod.Product_Status === 'Approved' || prod.Product_Status === 'Not Approved'"
```

Putting the `||` inside the string simply makes it part of the string, not a logical operator.

Answer (score 0):

You had wrong expression, it is basically comparing with `Approved||Not Approved` as string check. Better you could make use `indexOf` valid statuses array to make your implementation more compact.

```
ng-disabled="prod.Product_Status === isDisabled(prod.Product_Status)"
```

**Code**

```
//later you can add more status here in this array.
var validStatus = ['Approved', 'Not Approved']; 
$scope.isDisabled = function isDisabled(product_Status){
  return validStatus.indexOf(product_Status) > -1
}
```